# Is there a SQL function to expand table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

*I vaguely remember there being a function that does this, but I think I may be going crazy.*

Say I have a datatable, call it table1. It has three columns: column1, column2, column3. The query

```
 SELECT * FROM table1
```

returns all rows/columns from table1. Isn't there some type of EXPAND function that allows me to duplicate that result? For example, if I want to duplicate everything from the SELECT * FROM table1 query three times, I can do something like EXPAND(3) ?

Comment: CROSS JOIN the table with a tally table of 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BigQuery, I would recommend a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n;
```

This can get cumbersome for lots of copies, but you can simplify this by generating the numbers:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 3)) n
```

This creates an array with three elements and unnests it into rows.

In both these cases, you can include `n` in the `SELECT` to distinguish the copies.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I think below is close enough to what "got you crazy" o)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT copy.*
FROM `project.dataset.tabel1` t, UNNEST(FN.EXPAND(t, 3)) copy
```

To be able to do so, you can leverage recently [announced](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#November_22_2019) support for [persistent standard SQL UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), namely - you need to create FN.EXPAND() function as in below example (note: you need to have FN dataset in your project - or use existing dataset in which case you should use YOUR_DATASET.EXPAND() reference

```
#standardSQL
CREATE FUNCTION FN.EXPAND(s ANY TYPE, dups INT64) AS ( 
  ARRAY (
  SELECT s FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, dups)) 
  )
);
```

Finally, if you don't want to create persistent UDF - you can use temp UDF as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION EXPAND(s ANY TYPE, dups INT64) AS ( ARRAY(
  SELECT s FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, dups)) 
)); 
SELECT copy.*
FROM `project.dataset.tabel1` t, UNNEST(EXPAND(t, 3)) copy
```

Comment: Thats a more deep high level approach to what could be achieved via a union all or cartesian product and if really required can build a custom via embedding the cartesion or union query into a procedure( tablename) and can use whenever required

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/q/59305598/5221944 to see why/when this version can be quite useful :o)

Answer (score 1):

if you want  a cartesian product  (all the combination on a row ) you could use

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM table1 a
CROSS JOIN table1 b
CROSS JOIN table1 c
```

if you want the same rows  repeated  you can use UNION ALL

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use union all

```
  Select * from table1
   Union all
   Select * from table1
    Union all
   Select * from table1
   Union all
   Select * from table1
```

For reuse purposes can embed this code in a `procedure` like

```
   Create Procedure 
    expandTable(tablename 
     varchar2(50))
       As 
       Select * from table1
   Union all
   Select * from table1
    Union all
   Select * from table1
   Union all
   Select * from table1 
    End
    /
```