# Multiplying a timestamp data for several times in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-timestamp

I have a time-series starting from 2017-01-01 00:00:00 to the end of 2017-12-31 23:00:00 for 1-hour interval. I need to duplicate this 1-year timestamp for 2400 times in the same column. I need help about this one..

```
Row  Date_time  
1   2017-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
2   2017-01-01 01:00:00 UTC
3   2017-01-01 02:00:00 UTC
4   2017-01-01 03:00:00 UTC
5   2017-01-01 04:00:00 UTC
6   2017-01-01 05:00:00 UTC
7   2017-01-01 06:00:00 UTC
8   2017-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
...........................
...........................
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in BigQuery by generating a timestamp array and then unnesting:

```
 select ts
 from unnest(generate_timestamp_array('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-12-31 23:00:00', interval 1 hour)) ts
```

You can then get multiple rows with a similar construct:

```
 select ts
 from unnest(generate_timestamp_array('2017-01-01 00:00:00', '2017-12-31 23:00:00', interval 1 hour)
            ) ts cross join
      unnest(generate_series(1, 2400)) n
```

Comment: Actually I have already used this query to create 1-year timestamp. Now what I want is to multiply this time series for 2400 times. For exp, there must be 2400 times of 2017-01-01 00:00:00 in the same column.